# error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘&’ token

Tags: c++, g++

I wrote the following codes. The problem should be the istringstream function. what did I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
//read a string from input with a istringstream function and output the string   
word by word;
//1.the function takes and returns an istringstream&
//2.the function reads the stream until it hits eof
//the function should print the  contents of an istringstream object
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

istringstream& read(istringstream& input)
{

string string, word;
while(getline(input,string), !input.eof())
{
    if (input)      
    {
        istringstream instring(string);
        instring>>word;
        cout<<word<<'_'<<ends;
    }
    if (input.bad())
        throw runtime_error("data is corrupted");
    if (input.fail())
        cerr<<"data failed, try again"<<ends;
    input.close();
    input.clear();
}
return istringstream&;
}

int main ()
{   
    cout<<"enter a string"<<endl;
read(cin);
}
```

this output error is: (line 9)

```
 error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘&’ token
```

Comment: Please don't edit the question to change its meaning completely after other have answered. That just makes the answers unintelligible, and makes them worthless to future visitors. You could either: (a) edit your question and *append* the new, related problem to your original question, or (b) ask a separate question.

Comment: I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: No problem. :) Do post your second question though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those things are defined in the `std::` namespace.

If you are lazy you can `using namespace std;`, but it's not a good practice.

Comment: great, it worked, it's the namespace. also cin is not istringstream&. that was also the problem. the "input.eof()" check erases the last word of the string. ie. input string "hello world", output "hello_". why this happened?

Comment: switch eof and getline. and don't use comma, it's horrible.

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
return istringstream&;
```

to:

```
return input;
```

However given you don't use the returned value you could change the return type of `read()` to `void` and return nothing at all.

Comment: after changing to "return input;" still the same error. I am trying to write a istringstream function that returns istringstream. just to practice. so i want to find out what i am doing wrong here. thanks